# Remote Method Invocation over LAN network

Tags: java, networking, rmi, lan

Good day.

I'm trying to get 2 (very basic) java programs to communicate using RMI.

I'll first present my code and then describe my problem.

Here's the code for the server:

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements serverInterface
{
  public server() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {super(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);}
  public static String MSG = "Hi from server";
  public String getMessage()  {return MSG;}
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    server myServer = new server();
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    System.out.println("Server is up and registered");
    Naming.rebind("rmi://192.168.137.1:1099/test",myServer);
  }
}
```

Here's the code for the server interface:

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;


public interface serverInterface extends Remote
{
  public String getMessage() throws RemoteException;
}
```

And finally here's the code for the client:

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;


public class client
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Client is up");
    serverInterface obj = (serverInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.137.1:1099/test");
    System.out.println("Connected");
    System.out.println(obj.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Here's how it's gone so far and where I got stuck:

1- Connection on the same machine (via localhost): works perfectly fine.

2- Connection via LAN:

I created a hosted network via MS-DOS this way:

```
   netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=h key=0123456789
   netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

via ipconfig I saw that my ip adress in this LAN is 192.168.137.1

I had the server bound to that IP and had the client look it up, and everything also worked just fine.

Now here's the issue; I had a peer connect to my LAN and his IP was 192.168.137.56. Upon launching the client he gets the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.56.1; nested exception is:

        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getMessage(Unknown Source)
        at client.main(client.java:12)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

I don't get why the error reports a failed connection to 192.168.56.1 and not even the server's IP address (192.168.137.1).

What am I doing wrong or what's missing in order to get the expected result?

Thank you.

Comment: What's located at 192.168.56.1?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should follow naming conventions. Classes start with capital letters. `server` should be `Server`. `client` should be `Client`.

Comment: And what is the value of the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property on the server?

Comment: user1803551 I'm not sure exactly. I know how to override it but not how to monitor the current one.

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). Use @ to reply in comments.

Comment: The issue was resolved thank you. @user1803551

Comment: This is item A.1 in the RMI FAQ. @user1803551 It wouldn't have a value unless it was explicity set somewhere. Are you hinting that it should be set?

Comment: @EJP [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) it says "*The default value of this property is the IP address of the local host, in "dotted-quad" format.*". I didn't didn't test myself if this is true or if it wouldn't have a value. As for should it be set, I remember setting it solved a few problems with the OP's symptoms, so it's where I would start.

Comment: @user1803551 It's wrong. The default value *of what is written into the stub* is the IP address of the local host etc. I haven't said it shouldn't be set to solve this problem, although the underlying problem is actually a DNS/host misconfiguration: see RMI FAQ A.1. I was asking you what you meant by memtioning it.